# GStreamer: VBI data stream decoding

Tags: gstreamer

I have a question related to processing VBI data stream through 'teletextdec' plug-in.

Basically, I've already checked functionality of the next configuration:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v -m filesrc location=sample.mpeg ! tsdemux ! teletextdec ! videoconvert ! ximagesink`

where `sample.mpeg` is a video file containing not only video data, but also VBI data. Result is presented as video frames with overlayed VBI decoded VBI data.

At the moment, I'm interested to repeat similar configuration, but when video and VBI data are separated from each other (need to work with two data sources: one for video data providing, another for VBI data providing).

In other words, we have two next data sources:

/dev/vbi0 - is a character device, with binary data as an output

/dev/video0 - v4l2 device, with RAW data video as an output

I understand, that generally I need to have something like that:

`avfvideosrc name=src ! videomixer src.vbi_01 ! teletextdec`

Does anyone have similar experience?

Could anyone explain how correctly to execute mixing and decoding of RAW video data with VBI data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just an idea, not sure if it would work. You could try using a caps filter for your video and accepting only the video packets and reject the VBI data, or use it further in your application.

Comment: @vk_gst thanks for your attention, but we need here another behavior. We don't need here to filter one data from another, we're interested to mix two data sources with decoding the data source containing the VBI data.